# Stop Vertical scrolling of WebView in Tableview header

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

One of the cells in a UITableView contains a scroll view. I want to be able to scroll the content in the cell horizontally, but NOT vertically.

How can I achieve this?

Additionally, the scroll view is a subview of UIWebView, so I cannot control its content size.

I have tried setting the content offset directly, but this prevents the entire table from being scrolled. I want the table to scroll vertically, but not the content in the cell.

here is code of I stop vertical scrolling of webview in scrollview delegate-

initialisation of web-view here -

```
let bodyTextView: WKWebView = {
        // preferences
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.dataDetectorTypes = [.all]
        // webview
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        webView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        webView.scrollView.tag = 2
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
        return web
    }()

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //here is code to disable vertical scrolling for webview if scroll view tag is equal to 2 set while initialising the webview.
    if scrollView.tag ==2 { 
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0)
        }
    }
    //below code is used for Tableview-
      let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width
            pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)
     }
```

Comment: Show the code how you are controlling the delegate of the webview's scrollview. This should be easily possible. I guess your scrollview delegate also triggers for the tableview (as it also is a scrollview) and you are not differing there.

Comment: @MartinM Updated my code in question for scrollview delegate and initialising the webbview.  In scroll view delegate I am checking if tag is 2 for scrollview while modifying the contentOffest for scrollview. please let me know when is the issue here.

Comment: You are not setting the delegate though: webView.scrollView.delegate = self (or whatever implements UIScrollViewDelegate in your code).

Comment: @MartinM I set the delegate of scroll view and now control is coming to ScrollviewdidScroll delegate but facing same issue table view gets stop scrolling when i set the if scrollView.tag ==2 { 
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 0)
        }
    } in delegate